# Exchange WebDAV Save to Drafts NOT editable

Tags: c#, webdav, exchange-server-2003

I am having the following code to Save message to Exchange WEBDAV Drafts folder. IT saves the message but If open it in Outlook, Send button is Disabled and the message is readonly. Please help me find what am i missing in this code...

thanks
Bhuvan

```
 strBody = "To: " + strTo + "\n" +
                "Subject: " + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.Subject) ? "" : message.Subject) + "\n" +
            "Date: " + System.DateTime.Now + "\n" +
            "X-Mailer: test mailer" + "\n" +
            "MIME-Version: 1.0" + "\n" +
            "Content-Type: text/html;" + "\n" +
            "Charset = \"iso-8859-1\"" + "\n" +
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" + "\n" +
            "\n" + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.HtmlBody) ? "" : message.HtmlBody.Replace("<head />","").Replace("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">",""));

            // Create the HttpWebRequest object.
            PUTRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(tgtUri);

            // Add the network credentials to the request.
            // Use default credentials of the service to access the server.
            PUTRequest.Credentials = cred;


            // Specify the PUT method.
            PUTRequest.Method = "PUT"; //PROPPATCH

            // Encode the body using UTF-8.
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((string)strBody);

            // Set the content header length.  This must be
            // done before writing data to the request stream.
            PUTRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

            // Get a reference to the request stream.
            PUTRequestStream = PUTRequest.GetRequestStream();

            // Write the message body to the request stream.
            PUTRequestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            // Close the Stream object to release the connection
            // for further use.
            PUTRequestStream.Close();

            // Set the Content-Type header to the RFC 822 message format.
            PUTRequest.ContentType = "message/rfc822";

            // PUT the message in the Drafts folder of the
            // sender's mailbox.
            PUTResponse = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)PUTRequest.GetResponse();

            if (message.Attachments != null)
            {
                //Do the PROPPATCH
                System.Net.HttpWebRequest PROPPATCHRequest;
                System.Net.WebResponse PROPPATCHResponse;
                System.IO.Stream PROPPATCHRequestStream = null;

                string strxml = "<?xml version='1.0'?>" +
                "<d:propertyupdate xmlns:d='DAV:'>" +
                "<d:set>" +
                "<d:prop>" +
                "<isCollection xmlns='DAV:'>False</isCollection>" +
                "</d:prop>" +
                "</d:set>"
                + "<g:remove>"
                + "<g:prop><m:date/></g:prop>"
                + "</g:remove>" 
                + "</d:propertyupdate>";

                PROPPATCHRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(tgtUri);
                PROPPATCHRequest.Credentials = cred;
                PROPPATCHRequest.Headers.Set("Translate", "f");
                PROPPATCHRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
                PROPPATCHRequest.ContentLength = strxml.Length;
                PROPPATCHRequest.Method = "PROPPATCH";
                byte[] PROPPATCHbytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strxml);
                PROPPATCHRequest.ContentLength = PROPPATCHbytes.Length;
                PROPPATCHRequestStream = PROPPATCHRequest.GetRequestStream();
                PROPPATCHRequestStream.Write(PROPPATCHbytes, 0, PROPPATCHbytes.Length);
                PROPPATCHRequestStream.Close();
                PROPPATCHResponse = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)PROPPATCHRequest.GetResponse();


                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, byte[]> attachment in message.Attachments)
                {
                    System.IO.Stream PUTAttachRequestStream = null;
                    System.Net.HttpWebRequest PUTAttachRequest;
                    System.Net.WebResponse PUTAttachResponse;
                    //Attach File: This could be put in a loop to attach more than one file.
                    string FileName = attachment.Key; //@"2842498_794802035296_Label1.pdf";
                    string attachURI = tgtUri + "/" + FileName;
                    PUTAttachRequest = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(attachURI);
                    PUTAttachRequest.Credentials = cred;
                    PUTAttachRequest.Method = "PUT";

                    PUTAttachRequest.ContentLength = attachment.Value.Length; //binaryData.Length;
                    PUTAttachRequestStream = PUTAttachRequest.GetRequestStream();
                    PUTAttachRequestStream.Write(attachment.Value, 0, attachment.Value.Length); //(binaryData, 0, binaryData.Length);
                    PUTAttachRequestStream.Close();

                    PUTAttachResponse = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)PUTAttachRequest.GetResponse();
                    PUTAttachResponse.Close();
                }

                PROPPATCHResponse.Close();
            }

            // Clean up.
            PUTResponse.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in [Akash's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/akashb/archive/2008/10/06/8978425.aspx) on msdn. One has to carefully read this to get the actual answer, but the solution worked.